# Como sobrepor estilos CSS sem interferir em outro CSS anterior?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou implementando um modo de alto contraste, e para tal, estou utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

**Para chamar o alto contraste:**

```
<li><a href="#" class="seleciona-estilo" data-classe="classe-azul">MODO ESCURO</a></li>
```

**Javascript que adiciona o CSS**

```
<script>
$(".seleciona-estilo").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("link").attr("href", "ei-modo-escuro.css");
});
</script>
```

Minha dúvida é: quando clico no botão "Modo Escuro", a página carrega o CSS em questão e tudo fica como planejado, porém as outras configurações CSS anteriores são perdidas (como fontes, posicionamento e afins...). O que quero é apenas que o "Modo Escuro" substitua as cores de *background-color* e *color*, sem sobrepor todas as outras que não desejo alteração. Isso é possível?

Desde já agradeço! =]

Comment: Você pode postar o seu código completo com os estilos css.

Comment: Se não for muita CSS, pode criar duas classes, .claro e .escuro no CSS. Ao executar o click você usa $("link").addClass( "escuro"); e $("outro_link").removeClass( "escuro"); Ou pode usar .css("background", "#000");

Comment: Os estilos em comum nos dois "temas" devem ser colocado em um arquivo css que poderia ser chamado por exemplo de "estrutura.css", para cada novo "tema" teria de criar um arquivo css separado onde neles seriam adicionado somente os estilos individuais de cada um, no seu caso, só estilos de cores (background-color, color). Os css's de cores seriam carregados dinamicamente pelo jquery. Fazendo desta forma, a estrutura não vai mudar já que estaria carregando o "estrutura.css" que é comum para ambos, o que iria mudar seria somente as cores do seu aplicativo, nos temas individuais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar ou remover apenas uma classe no body, para depois incluí-la nos seletores do estilo escuro:

```
$(".bt-tema").on("click", function(e) {
  $('body').toggleClass("escuro");
});
```

Colocando as instruções do escuro por último, elas são aplicadas após as instruções padrão:

```
/* Tema normal */
body {}
h1 {}
p {}

/* Tema escuro */
.escuro {}
.escuro h1 {}
.escuro p {}
```

Veja funcionando aqui: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpJVAq

Comment: Testei dessa forma e funcionou exatamente como eu desejo, Ezequias! Muitíssimo obrigado, meu caro! Não só a você, mas também a todos os outros que me ajudaram nas respostas acima.

Comment: Disponha @Vítor. Poderia marcar a resposta como aceita, por favor?
Assim ganho uns pontinhos e também as próximas pessoas vão saber qual é.
Abraços